# An option to turn off the skin (revert to something like the default "beta" skin for sites)

Tags: feature-request

The skin here is really messing with my eyes, and I'm having trouble understanding what I see when on this SE site, when compared to others.

I'd like to request an option to turn off the skin and revert to a default, un-skinned site (maybe similar to the beta sites)

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser add-ons to over write site's styles. For example: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

To revert back to the Beta theme, you can grab the CSS file from any of the current Beta sites, for example: http://sstatic.net/guitars/all.css Please keep in mind once the Beta site launches officially the .CSS file content will change. You'll need to grab a CSS file from another Beta site.

Comment: Oy. That's a cludge. Besides not working with my ipad, it means I'll have to manually add each site to the configuration, and synch across all the computers I use. I'd rather have a checkbox that fixes the problem once, forever - and I don't think that's something I can do myself